# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" in Docker on Windows (Solved)

Tags: postgresql, authentication, docker

I had two bridged docker containers, one containing a PostgreSQL database the other pgAdmin4. I was also connecting to the database from QGIS and MS Excel on my local machine. However sometimes the connection would not authenticate the user from the local machine but would always do so from the containerized pgAdmin.  Installing pgAdmin locally did not help.

Comment: There aren't many good reasons to want to connect as `postgres` from anything but pgAdmin. Best practice is to create a number of non-administrative logins and roles to manage access.

Answer (score 0):

The most common advice I found online was to adjust the authentication method to 'TRUST', which is inadvisable for non-personal use anyway but also took some time to figure out in Docker so I will include it here in case that is your issue:

```
docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> /bin/bash
cd /var/lib/postgresql/data
echo "host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust" >> pg_hba.conf
cat pg_hba.conf
docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> service postgresql restart
```

However, it turned out my issue was nothing to do with the authentication process per se. When authenticating a user on a Postgres database in a Docker container, from the local machine (e.g. pgAdmin, QGIS or other ODBC on the local machine) if there is any version of Postgres installed locally it will intercept the connection request. If both the containerized and local versions are different it will then return an authentication error.

One suggested solution I found is to use a different port from 5432, however I could not get a connection on any other port to work. So I eventually uninstalled the local postgres which resolved the issue.